# Fetch full page from wikipedia using Wikipedia API

Tags: android, json, api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to get a all the contents from this page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes

for an Android App, however when I use wikipedia API like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

I don't get all the contents of the page. If I search for the name of an episode such as "cancer man" in the returned json string, I get nothing.

What am I missing in the query string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query gives complete result in as a string value of key "*". If you try to [edit the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes&action=edit), you would see that for each season you see something like this for season 1:

```
=== Season 1 (2008) ===
{{Main|Breaking Bad (season 1)}}
{{:Breaking Bad (season 1)}}
```

The last line is a [wikipedia template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Template), which you can find it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Breaking_Bad_episodes).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, `action=raw&expandtemplates=1` might be a solution. (This is not an API, just [query parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Raw) you can append to any page URL. E.g. [`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes?action=raw&expandtemplates=1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes?action=raw&expandtemplates=1))